# what's the outer product of two row vectors

Tags: python, matrix

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) gives the outer product of column vectors $a$ and $b$ like this
$$
a=\begin{bmatrix}a_{1}
\\ a_{2}
\\ a_{3}
\end{bmatrix},
b=\begin{bmatrix}b_{1}
\\ b_{2}
\\ b_{3}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
a⊗b=ab^{T}=\begin{bmatrix}a_{1}b_{1}\space \space a_{1}b_{2}\space \space a_{1}b_{3}
\\a_{2}b_{1}\space \space a_{2}b_{2}\space \space a_{2}b_{3}
\\a_{3}b_{1}\space \space a_{3}b_{2}\space \space a_{3}b_{3}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
If $a$ and $b$ are rows vector,
according to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/796709/kronecker-product-and-outer-product-confusion) the outer product should be like this 
$$
a=\begin{bmatrix} a_{1} \space \space a_{2} \space \space a_{3}\end{bmatrix},
b=\begin{bmatrix} b_{1} \space \space b_{2} \space \space b_{3}\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
a⊗b=a⊗_{K}b^{T}=\begin{bmatrix}a_{1}b_{1}\space \space a_{2}b_{1}\space \space a_{3}b_{1}
\\a_{1}b_{2}\space \space a_{2}b_{2}\space \space a_{3}b_{2}
\\a_{1}b_{3}\space \space a_{2}b_{3}\space \space a_{3}b_{3}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
But when I do it in python [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), it gives the same answer like this.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])
b = np.array([[4], [5], [6]])
col_result=np.outer(a, b)
row_result=np.outer(a.T, b.T)
print(col_result)
print(row_result)
```

the answer is like this:

```
[[ 4  5  6]
 [ 8 10 12]
 [12 15 18]]
[[ 4  5  6]
 [ 8 10 12]
 [12 15 18]]
```

So,do I write a wrong equations or python do it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is a question for https://stackoverflow.com/

However, here is the answer: numpy flattens the input into 1D arrays, no matter what the shape. You should instead calculate

```
 np.outer(b,a)
```